# Can't access array value using variables

Tags: javascript

i am using the [p5js](https://p5js.org) libary and ran into a problem that i have never had before. I have a function called neighbors with the constructor neighbors(x, y). I call that function multiple times each loop (2500 times). If i use this code:

```
if(x < 50){
    if(spots[1][1]){
        neighborCount++;
    }
}
```

nothing goes wrong. As soon as i replace the code with this:

```
if(x < 50){
    if(spots[parseInt(x+1)][1]){
        neighborCount = 3;
    }
}
```

I get an error in the console:

> TypeError: spots[(x + 1)] is undefined

I tried using

```
spots[parseInt(x+1)][1]
```

but that only changed the error to

> TypeError: spots[parseInt(...)] is undefined

I hope i explained my problem well enough and you can understand it. If i forgot something please tell me i will add it as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance

FritzFurtz

Comment: What is `x`? And why do you use `parseInt` on what appears to be a number?

Comment: What is `spots`? Does it contain that many items?

Comment: i think spots length  less than x+1

Comment: x is a number between 0 and 49. Oh i think i just found my mistake. I check if x < 50 but it is always smaller 50. Let me check that now. Oh yes. Array 0 indexing... Thanks for asking questions, that always help :)

Comment: but x+1 when x=49 => x+1=50 its out of range

Answer (score 1):

I did a classic mistake: 0 indexing in arrays. The if(x < 50) was supposed to check if it is undefinded, because the array size is 50. But i forgot that the last value is indexed 49 so i have to check if(x < 49). Thank you guys for always answering fast!

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: I access x+1. If i do that i have to check that x + 1 is not undefined and for that i made a if(x < 50), because the array size is 50. But since arrays are 0 indexed, i had to make a if(x < 49) so that x + 1 can be max. 49

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
if(x < 50){
    if(spots[parseInt(x,10)+1][1]){
        neighborCount = 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: TypeError: spots[(parseInt(...) + 1)] is undefined. Thanks for the fast answer anyway :)